# PyMongo alternative to findAndModify

Tags: python, mongodb, multithreading, multiprocessing, pymongo

**Background:**
Python 3.7, Mongo 4.4, Ubuntu 20.04

I want to add a sequence number (unique integer) to new documents in my application. I'm holding a counter in the DB and using it as the unique number, increasing it after each new document.

Since my application is multi-processed, I sync this counter between processes using pyMongo `findAndModify` function, which is atomic (see [Atomicity and Transactions](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/)).

Here is a simplified example of the code:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
db = client['data']
collection = db.counters

query = {'_id' = 'sequence_data'}
update = {'$inc':{ 'counter':1}}

updated_doc = collection.find_and_modify(query, update)
return updated_doc['counter']
```

**Problem:**
The `findAndModify` function is deprecated (see [PyMongo 4.0  changelog](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changelog.html#changes-in-version-4-0)), and following the guidelines in [PyMongo 4 Migration Guide](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrate-to-pymongo4.html#collection-find-and-modify-is-removed), i tried to use the `find_one_and_update` function, but it is not atomic for the find part.

This can cause a race condition between 2 processes that execute the `find_one_and_update` and both read the same counter value, before incrementing it.

**Question:**
So my basic question is, how do I apply atomicity on the read section of my logic between multiple processes/threads?

Comment: I don't know about the atomicity of the `pymongo` collection commands, but if you really want to use [`findAndModify`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/), could you use it with `pymongo`'s `db.command`?